# Illegal offset type in isset or empty (View: file.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am getting an error in my file.blade.php but every thing in file is correct

**traces**

FileViewFinder.php (line 71)

```
public function find($name)    {        
if (isset($this->views[$name])) {
```

Error starts from line 71 of FileViewFinder.php

any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you provide *all* of your relevant code please. So include the function that returns your blade view and the blade view itself.

Comment: I think that your variable ($name) didn't take a value and that cause you a null offset please dd your $name variable and check if it had a value
or maybe you can show us more of your code

Answer (score 1):

Try using **array_key_exists** function

```
if (array_key_exists($name, $this->views)) {
...

}
```